Magento 2 : Error of cookieMessagesObservable is not defined
I have updated the Magento to 2.4.7 recently and updated it to the staging server. I am getting the error that cookieMessagesObservable is not defined in the console and due to this  Minicart is not accessible to me and several js are also not loading due to it.
Check the below image for the reference:-


cookieMessagesObservable is not defined in core Magento codebase, you will have to look into your code base for it and post the file(s) having reference to this variable so people can help you debug it.

I am having same issue , can you find any solution @Aman ?

I @aman Can you find any solution ?

I have tried installing Magento to the latest version using Composer install.
After that check, the message.js file is overrided in my custom module or app/design and changed on the overridden file as per the vendor message.js file.
By doing the changes it helps me solve the issue.

Do we have any other possible solution in this? message.js is generated again after deployment in the static/*version*/frontend/*ThemeVendor*/*ThemeName*/Magento_Theme/js/view/messages.js
But still error was there in the console.

You most likely need to redeploy static content. Either delete all everything in the folders pub/static/frontend and pub/static/adminhtml and run:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

This might take a few minutes, after make sure your browser isn't caching any of the old files, and refresh this should resolve the problem.
You are looking for a file to update called messages.js it should be in
static/*version*/frontend/*ThemeVendor*/*ThemeName*/Magento_Theme/js/view/messages.js

Hope this helps
