Magento 2.4.7 Minicart not showing

knockout.js:3753 Uncaught ReferenceError: cookieMessagesObservable is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:3221:28), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:4820:71)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2331:115)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2288:41)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2253:40)
    at ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:2085:40)
    at init (knockout.js:4819:32)
    at knockout.js:3730:58
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1563:45)
    at knockout.js:3729:60


Please follow the last comment, as the individual experiencing the same issue has provided the solution himself, please follow the link hope it helps. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/373362/magento-2-error-of-cookiemessagesobservable-is-not-defined

@SuSu Dev
Hey,
You need to set default looma theme.Firstly run all the commands and check, if it shows mini cart it is an issue related to custom theme.
Thank You!
